# Do people tend to spend less when using cash than credit cards?

Tags: credit-card, budget, cash

I know this is a popular theory on this site and finance blogs/media in general, but I'd like to know if there is any reliable research on the subject.  I can share personal experience that makes me think it's true, and there is plenty of anecdotal evidence, but I'm hoping for something more concrete either way - I'm not trying to justify a position, but earnestly looking for the right answer.

Here's some specific aspects I've heard and/or have personally experienced:

- The emotional/psychological difference in handing over cash versus swiping a card or buying on a phone
- Easier to stay on budget with a depletable resource (vs. a line of credit)
- More bargaining power with cash. I have tried this on smaller purchases (e.g. appliances) and haven't been successful - have not tried it on larger purchases (e.g. car)
- Incentives to overspend to earn points/miles/rewards
- Cash can "burn a hole in your pocket" - meaning it's tempting to use it just because it's there.
- Cards give you a itemized breakdown of where you've been spending, making it easier to see where your money is going

Are there any specific studies or research that indicates whether people in general spend less when using cash?

I'm specifically interested in situations where cash vs card is a reasonable option - meaning retail discretionary spending (not monthly bills). I'm also not wanting proof that it applies to everyone universally.  I'm more interested in knowing if the statement is appropriate when dealing with finances in general.  Certainly there's a lot of room for individual responsibility/discipline/behavior.

**EDIT** - added a few bullets and clarifications from the answers below.

Comment: Can you give a specific scenario for the third bullet?

Comment: @Nosrac Go to an appliance store to buy a refrigerator, and pull out cash when negotiating. Are you more likely to get a discount?  It probably works better with cars or houses, but I'm more interested in day-to-day spending.

Comment: [Credit Cards Make You Spend More](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/credit-cards-make-you-spend-more/) Points to a number of studies that support the assertion in the title

Comment: @DStanley It probably would depend greatly on the kind of business that you were buying from. On one side of the spectrum, you have an individual selling a car who might not want to wait for a buyer to secure credit but instead sell to the buyer who has cash ready to go. On the other, you have large car dealerships which often make a large part of their revenue from financing.

Comment: @Nosrac Agree completely, and for appliances, big-box stores are probably less likely than local appliance stores.

Comment: I think there was an episode on BBC or C4 where it specifically showed this. With cash we tend to spend less than if we use card.

Comment: Anecdotally, I've found that the 25-55 day buffer offered by credit cards has been a big factor in spending.  Before I had cards, I was far more frugal with a debit card.  I haven't used cash much in 10 years or so.

Comment: @JaredStroeb - nice link. All I saw there was a link to [Why Nearly Every Purchase Should Be on a Credit Card](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/why-every-purchase-should-be-on-a-credit-card/)  Excellent article.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer A good article, a bit self serving if we assume NerdWallet makes revenue on its Credit Card recommendations.  I was referencing the three links to outside sources, primarily [Do Payment Mechanisms Change the Way Consumers Perceive Products](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/239810637_Do_Payment_Mechanisms_Change_the_Way_Consumers_Perceive_Products). The citations provide good information.

Comment: The more answers I see the more I think this would be a better question for the Skeptics Exchange.

Comment: Yes. The longer you wait to count your money, the lesser psychological impact it has on you (which is what banks are after). When you pay cash, you count your money **before** making a purchase, which is the earliest moment possible. For example, you are going to spend 500$ of hard earned cash on a piece of furniture. Do you really need it that much? Would you buy it at all? Or - your monthly bill is 5000$ - sure the amount is big, but you'll pay it anyway, right? There is no way you'll have all receipts at hand to really see where your money went at that point.

Comment: Too late to add this to the question now, but in addition to the behavioral difference between cash and credit cards, it would also be interesting to look at the behavioral difference with debit cards. -- Relevant as some answers are about 'cards' whilst there may be a significant difference between debit and credit.

Comment: One more point that you forgot: you can't go into debt with cash, but you *can* with credit cards. Cash doesn't allow you to spend money you don't have yet.

Comment: Wrt to your point 3: I'd put this in a somewhat different way saying that there are situations that characteristically combine negotiations/bargaining with cash payments. I'm talking from garage sale and flea market to buying used appliances or cars (from private persons, but also the corresponding second hand traders in my experience expect and are open to negotiations). Negotiations can only take place when also the sales person can (is allowed to) negotiate - which is typically not the case for cashiers in supermarket-style electronics/appliances stores. For bigger, customized things ...

Comment: ... (industrial machinery) there's anyways negotiation about the exact offer, and then instead of cash payment, you may negotiate for discount for early payment (German term: Skonto).

Comment: An an anecdotal answer.    My daughter is very careful about using her debit card, and strives to keep her account balance high.  She appears to be much more willing to spend any and all physical money.

Comment: Also anecdotal, but another factor to consider: I personally do not like carrying cash for a variety of reasons I wont get into. So if I come into cash (gift, refund, etc.) I tend to spend more quickly just to get rid of it.

Comment: There is a key factor here, which is how much cash is available. Limited/unlimited cash will force a different behavior,  the same way that a lower limit in a credit card will.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - the studies, I linked to 5, also have some references to debit cards.

Comment: Spending only cash creates a very crude budget constraint. If you already have a (more elaborate) budget, you can use your card and still have a budget constraint, i.e. no difference between card and cash in spending behavior.

Comment: Cash burns a hole in **my** pocket.  CCs *used to* let me think, "I'll pay for it later". **Using a debit card** (plus a spreadsheet check register) was how we broke the habit of overspending.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I found the study "[The irrationality of payment behaviour](https://www.dnb.nl/en/binaries/OS%201104%20WEB_tcm47-294816.pdf)" accidentally while searching on the term "DNB Study" instead of "D&B Study".  [This study](https://www.dnb.nl/en/binaries/OS%201104%20WEB_tcm47-294816.pdf), which, when I followed the link, went to the web site dnb.nl (Dutch National Bank), instead of dnb.com (Dun & Bradstreet).  It mentions all the salient points that I hear Dave Ramsey and others mention when they talk about studies on this subject of credit vs cash.  Also, it cross references to many other studies by various researchers, banks, and universities.  Is this the "missing mythical DNB study?"  I'll let you decide.  Relevant "coincidental" points from the study:

- Payment method influences the level of pain when paying (Chatterjee and Rose, 2012).
- "consumers make use of the fact that cash allows one to see at a glance not only what one has available to spend, but also how much one has already spent" (Deutsche Bundesbank, 2011)
- DNB used a functional MRI study to measure the brain's response to the emotional choice between cash and card.

To be fair and complete, I should mention that clearly the relevant parts of this DNB study are talking about discretionary spending.  Auto-paying your mortgage with a card is clearly not going to cost you more (unless you somehow forget to pay off the card or some other silliness).

Comment: It's worth mentioning that DNB and D&B would be pronounced nearly identically by many Americans. I've listened to Ramsey a few times, and I believe he would be in the group that pronounces them the same.

Comment: The next step if it were specifically about Dave would be to see when he first mentioned the DNB study and see if it was before this study was released.

Comment: I was going to interject my personal opinion in this answer, but I think it stands well by itself.  Personally, however, I feel there is a very large segment of the population who don't have the discipline to budget with a credit card because of this "lack of emotional pain", but there is another smaller segment who "bring down the average", if you will, who live on a strict budget, and have the discipline to not impulse buy or change their purchase decision based on plastic.  And of course, there are also those who believe they're in the second group, above all influence, but really aren't.

Comment: @Erik Indeed, I would be interested to know that answer too!  But I'm betting that would take a lot more research to dig up, which I don't have time for right now (or some further lucky accidental internet search finds).

Comment: I'm ready for more drum and bass studies

Comment: "cash allows one to see at a glance not only what one has available to spend, but also how much one has already spent" I think there was "not" dropped here, as cash certainly offers on way to tell how much was already spent, unlike card.

Answer (score 43):

> I'd like to know if there is any reliable research on the subject.

Intuitively, this *must* be true, no? Is it? First, is it even possible to discover the correlation, if one exists? Dave Ramsey is a proponent of "Proven study that shows you will spend 10% more on a credit card than with cash." Of course, he suggests that the study came from an otherwise reliable source, Dun & Bradstreet. A fellow blogger at [Get Rich Slowly](http://www.getrichslowly.org/blog/2010/04/27/money-myths-and-the-importance-of-thinking-for-yourself/) researched and found -

> Nobody I know has been able to track down this mythical Dun and
>   Bradstreet study. Even Dun and Bradstreet themselves have been unable
>   to locate it. GRS reader Nicole (with the assistance of her trusty
>   librarian Wendi) contacted the company and received this response:
>   “After doing some research with D&B, it turns out that someone made up
>   the statement, and also made up the part where D&B actually said
>   that.”

In other words, the most cited study is a Myth.

In fact, there are studies which do conclude that card users spend more. I think that any study (on anything, not just this topic. Cigarette companies buy studies to show they don't cause cancer, Big Oil pays to disprove global warming, etc.) needs to be viewed with a critical eye. The studies I've seen nearly all contain one of 2 major flaws -

- Behaviors are contrived. Specifically, the studies don't observe real life, they take a snapshot of behaviors of people choosing between a gift card and cash for a food purchase. Such studies don't hold up well to extrapolation to a full family grown up budget.
- Study itself is flawed. It's important to understand how statistics work, and what makes for a valid observation. Some time ago, a study came out linking coffee drinking to cancer. I immediately told my wife the study was a joke (as in 'flawed' not an attempt at humor). When the study was debunked some time later, the false correlation was revealed. Coffee drinkers have a higher propensity to smoke than non-drinkers. The coffee --> cancer was a false correlation. Or rather correlation without causation. The paper vs plastic studies that otherwise would be valid fail to separate the obvious 2 groups among card users. Those who pay in full vs those who carry a balance. Say only 1/3 pay in full, and have no impact from spending. 2/3 use card, carrying balance, but actually spend 15% more. The summary line is still "card users spend 10% more."

---

My own observation - when I reviewed our budget over the course of a year, some of the largest charges include -

- Insurance Home, Car, Life
- Medical costs
- Dance classes (my daughter's career choice, a hefty annual expense)
- TV/Cable/Cell
- Gas (2 cars, 3 drivers)

I list the above, as these are items whose cost is pretty well fixed. We are not in the habit of "going for a drive," gas is bought when we need it. All other items I consider fixed, in that the real choice is to pay with the card or check, unlike the items some claim can be inflated. These add to about 80% of the annual card use. I don't see it possible for card use to impact these items, and therefore the "10% more" warning is overreaching.

To conclude, I'll concede that even the pay-in-full group might not adhere to the food budget, and grab the $5 brownie near the checkout, or over tip on a restaurant meal. But those situations are not sufficient to assume that a responsible card user comes out behind over the year for having done so.

---

A selection of the Studies I am referencing -

- [Always Leave Home Without It](http://web.mit.edu/simester/Public/Papers/Alwaysleavehome.pdf)
- [Do Payment Mechanisms Change the Way Consumers Perceive Products?](http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/661730?origin=JSTOR-pdf&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)
- [Monopoly Money: The Effect of Payment Coupling and Form on Spending Behavior](http://www.apa.org/pubs/journals/releases/xap143213.pdf)
- [The Impact of Credit Cards on Spending: A Field Experiment](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=1378502)
- [Spending and credit cards](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/ulterior-motives/201001/spending-and-credit-cards)

Comment: Anecdotal, but I have caught myself spending more with a CC then I would have with cash.

Comment: and corsika's comment is a vote for the opposite. I don't doubt for a minute that's it true in the aggregate, and might agree that 2/3 or more of people should heed the warning.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer, While I agree with your last paragraph, you've narrowed the group to "responsible card user[s]."  (without any study to substantiate what I'm about to say:) I'd venture that most plastic is being swiped by irresponsible people.  As with any behavioral study, there will be a macro finding "on average, people studied [whatever]" and the individuals included in the study will fall in the spectrum somewhere.  Will JoeTaxpayer spend more on on credit cards, probably not; will everyone on average, I'd venture the answer is yes because "everyone" includes a lot of irresponsible people.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "fixed expense" in the sense you are using the phrase. If there was some major market disruption and the price of gas went to $20 per gallon tomorrow, I suspect you'd find ways to save gas. Like maybe combine errands or reduce the distance you are willing to drive for dining out or entertainment. If gas went to $100 per gallon, you might buy a more fuel-efficient car, take the bus, or walk. If cell phone rates went up you might decide to get plans with fewer minutes. Etc. Until you're at the point where you're eating mac & cheese every meal and living in ...

Comment: ... a cardboard box under a bridge, there are ways to economize.

Comment: @Jay - I appreciate your pointing that out. I misuse the word 'fixed'. I was trying to make a distinction between clothes/food/toys where one can easily spend 3X vs those that don't come under my budget as an item I feel worth cutting.

Comment: @quid - I think you got it. My issue stems from the Dave Ramsey quote ["Responsible use of a credit card does not exist."](https://www.daveramsey.com/blog/the-truth-about-credit-card-debt) This unsubstantiated statement is what set me off years ago. If you were completely omniscient, you might report back that only 10% of card users are better off. Higher, lower, I literally cannot know, I only know that zero is an absurd statement. A non-card user would have a logistical set of hoops to jump through to rent a car or hotel room or buy an airline ticket.

Comment: I think you're straw-manning this "card users spend 10% more" claim. 10% *of what*? Who is claiming that card users spend 10% more on home insurance? Why do you consider it implausible that those who somehow manage to purchase home insurance with cash are also, on average, spending 9% less on it? Are those same people claiming that card users spend 10% more on their house, and if so is that absolute (i.e. they live in bigger houses in nicer areas) or relative (they pay more for the same size house in the same area) or just that they pick worse mortgages? There's a lot of interpretation there.

Comment: I'm trusting that 'they' mean that a credit card purchase is typically 10% higher than the user would otherwise spend. Not on a house or mortgage, of course, but most else, i.e. anything one can charge.

Comment: Yeah, so if they mean that my cable package will somehow get 10% more expensive if I switch from paying by direct debit to paying by credit card, that does seem nonsensical. So are "they" the right people to be arguing with, or are there some more sensible people making more sensible claims, whose published research would constitute an answer to this question?

Comment: And in particular which somehow eliminates the subjective elements in your own personal research methodology. "I own a credit card, and I don't spend so much as 10% more than I absolutely have to. Therefore it is inconceivable that those who own credit cards spend 10% more than those who don't, let alone that the credit card is the cause of that". Not that I'm saying it is 10%, just that the research you present doesn't convince me it cannot be :-) I have a credit card but don't use it much, so I don't even know which dog to back in this fight.

Comment: @SteveJessop et al Let's dispose of straw men. If anyone is saying that people who use credit cards pay 10% more for houses or cars ... I think that's very unlikely. Cable TV? Probably not. The real argument is that when someone walks into a store to buy something, the person who takes his shopping cart to the cash register and pays with a credit card spends 10% more than the person who pays cash. I don't know if it's true, but it seems quite plausible. It doesn't seem shocking to suppose that someone who has $100 in his wallet and pays cash will limit his purchases to $100, while ...

Comment: ... someone who has $100 at home or in the bank and who pays with a credit card might spend $110, thinking, when the bill comes in, I'll find a way to pay it. Or not even thinking about just how much money he really has available because his credit limit is $5000, so he can spend $5000.

Comment: There's useful info here, but the question is "Are there any specific studies or research that indicates whether people in general spend less when using cash?"  I think that means answers should cite specific studies.  The only study you specifically cite is one that you note doesn't exist.  You allude to other studies with the same result but don't have any references, and the rest of your answer is just about your own personal opinion, not actual studies.  Not to say that your opinion isn't interesting, but the question is asking for *research studies*, and you didn't answer that.

Comment: @BrenBarn - you are 100% correct. How many would I need to cite to satisfy your objection (and reverse the DV)?

Comment: I think part of the difficulty is that "Do people tend to spend less when using cash than credit cards?" actually covers several different questions: E.g. Are people who prefer to use CC spending more? Do people who spend more prefer CC over cash? In general? For a particular intended act of spending? If I know someone uses CC rather than cash, can I predict that they spend more than when the same person spends cash for the same type of purchase? Given a person that is overspending with CC, will this actually change if they switch to cash? It is not possible to judge a study without being ...

Comment: ... very specific on what the question of interest is. E.g. your example of the study with coffee drinking smoker's cancer: of course, it doesn't help at all establishing *causes* of cancer. But if you are screening and "coffee drinker" is an easy-to-measure/ask surrogate, while "smoker" is a difficult/expensive-to-test true cause for elevated cancer risk, it may be sensible to use "coffee drinker" status for deciding who screen more closely. Similarly, for finding people with risky financial behaviour, a correlation of oversepending with CC use can be useful regardless of hens and eggs.

Comment: For what it's worth, the origin of this Q&A is in the quote ["There is no positive side to credit card use. You will spend more if you use credit cards."](https://www.daveramsey.com/blog/the-truth-about-credit-card-debt) and the followup statistic that card users spend about 10% more than cash buyers.

Comment: There's another answer that suggests the cited study is not a myth and instead, it's incorrectly being attributed to Dun & Bradstreet.

Comment: Respectfully, the DNB study was authored 2013. The Mythical D&B study has haunted me for well over a decade.

Comment: that's important to know: the "get rich slowly" page you linked says it was updated last year.

Comment: Understood. We (bloggers) frequently revisit older articles and refresh/update with new information. And NOTE - The GRS post URL shows 2010/04/27, so even though it was edited, the original publish date was in 2010.

Comment: Overall 10% higher spending *can* plausibly be true even if the fraction of purchases that can be done by CC or cash is small: i.e. if if CC preference is positively correlated with *generally* higher/over spending. This is something easily measureable by studies. However, even if that were the case to the extent claimed, the somewhat implied advise to "drop the CC and go with cash" alone will not plausibly take care of overspending with the fixed costs... which is a totally different question, but also one that could rather easily be studied.

Comment: It's actually plausible that people spend more on houses due to access to credit (mortgages, obviously, not credit cards). And on a market level, lots of people having access to credit means lots of people pay more for houses, so even cash buyers pay more, and even renters pay more rent (this is far from proven, but plausible).

Comment: @stannius - to that point - Well written article states "Mortgage interest deduction does not promote home ownership." At first blush, that seemed crazy. The article concluded the deduction encouraged a *larger* home purchase, not the purchase itself.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: I've removed the downvote based on the great references you gave.  I do still think your answer's ratio of research to personal commentary is not justified by the question, but it does answer the question now.

Comment: @BrenBarn - thank you. You are still 100% correct. It was a visceral response to my own history with the higher level subject matter. Still voted high of the 9 answers, but you're right that I went completely off-topic.

Answer (score 26):

[Psychology Today had an interesting article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/the-science-behind-behavior/201607/does-it-matter-whether-you-pay-cash-or-credit-card) from July 11, 2016, in which they go through the psychological aspects of using cash vs. a credit card. This article cites a [2008 paper in the Journal of Experimental Psychology: Applied](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/xap/14/3/213/) that found:

> “the more transparent the payment outflow, the greater the aversion to spending or higher the ‘pain of paying’ …leading to less transparent payment modes such as credit cards and gift cards (vs. cash) being more easily spent or treated as play or ‘monopoly money.’”

The article cites a number of other studies that are of interest on this topic as well.

Comment: Ironically, my wife and I strive to put everything on our card so there is MORE transparency because there's a record and we can review what we spent our money on. You'll never notice how much you spend on coffee when it's 2 or 3 bucks at a time, but when you whip out the spreadsheet and you realize there's a hundred bucks spent on it, you start to rethink. Of course, you have to be more diligent about paying it off AND about actually reviewing it...

Comment: I agree that credit cards can provide better visibility and accountability.  With tools like https://personalcapital.com around it is pretty easy to see where your money is going whether it is checks or credit cards.  Sadly most people are using credit cards without such ease of reflection.

Comment: @corsiKa: well, that's just an artefact of you and your wife being woefully slack about demanding each other's receipts ;-)

Comment: @SteveJessop Actually it's because my wife does a lot of arbitrage and consequently has a float to buy things (where they don't often give receipts...). It becomes difficult to separate which cash is ours and which cash is her operation's.

Comment: Best answer. Also check videos related to human psychology by Dan Ariely.

Comment: @corsiKa we do the same thing, and I created an answer to reflect that way of thinking and the value it gives to your budget short and long-term

Answer (score 22):

Others have commented on the various studies. If, as JoeTaxpayer says, this one particular study he mentions does not really exist, there are plenty of others. (And in that case: Did someone blatantly lie to prove a bogus point? Or did someone just get the name of the organization that did the study wrong, like it was really somebody called "B&D", they read it as "D&B" because they'd heard of Dun & Bradstreet but not of whoever B&D is. Of course if they got the organization wrong maybe they got important details of the study wrong. Whatever.)

But let me add one logical point that I think is irrefutable: If you always buy with cash, there is no way that you can spend more than you have. When you run out of cash, you have no choice but to stop spending. But when you buy with a credit card, you can easily spend more than you have money in the bank to pay. Even if it is true that most credit card users are responsible, there will always be some who are not, and credit cards make it easy to get in trouble.

I speak from experience. I once learned that my wife had run up $20,000 in credit card debt without my knowledge. When she divorced me, I got stuck with the credit card debt. To this day I have no idea what she spent the money on. And I've known several people over the years who have gone bankrupt with credit card debt.

Even if you're responsible, it's easy to lose track with credit cards. If you use cash, when you take out your wallet to buy something you can quickly see whether there's a lot of money left or not so much. With credit, you can forget that you made the big purchase. More likely, you can fail to add up the modest purchases. It's easy to say, "Oh, that's just $100, I can cover that." But then there's $100 here and $100 there and it can add up. (Or depending on your income level, maybe it's $10 here and $10 there and it's out of hand, or maybe it's $10,000.) It's easier today when you can go on-line and check the balance on your credit card. But even at that, well just this past month when I got one bill I was surprised at how big it was. I went through the items and they were all legitimate, they just ... added up. Don't cry for me, I could afford it. But I had failed to pay attention to what I was spending and I let things get a little out of hand. I'm a pretty responsible person and I don't do that often. I can easily imagine someone paying less attention and getting into serious trouble.

Comment: "When you run out of cash, you have no choice but to stop spending" is only true while at the store. Next stop is hitting up your friends/relatives/acquaintances for a loan, which is what over-spenders used to do before credit cards became commonplace and what people with bad credit still do today. "I would gladly pay you Tuesday for a hamburger today"

Comment: If you always buy with cash, there is no way that you can spend more than you have.

Comment: @JerryNixon-MSFT oh really? Say that all those poor shop owners forced to sell "on notebook" even if many customers never pay out fully...

Comment: @JaredSmith I think it's worth pointing out that approaching your friends/relatives/acquaintances have more effort involved to it. The notorious over-spenders might not be affected by it, but those that are in the middle of the bell curve would certainly factor it in.

Comment: @Rystraum good point

Comment: @JaredSmith Sure. Credit cards aren't the only way to borrow. You could borrow from friends or relatives like you say, get a second mortgage on your house, etc. The point is "paying with cash" versus "borrowing". Credit cards are a particularly easy way to borrow, but certainly not the only way.

Comment: @Jay yes there are two ways to attack the failure mode: the people angle and the process angle. I just wanted to comment that you have to consider *both*, and address the underlying motivations of the spender.

Comment: @user45830 Buying "on notebook" is a form of credit. It's not buying with cash.

Answer (score 16):

First, let me answer the question the best way I can: I don't know if there are any studies other than those that have already been mentioned.

Now, let's talk about something more interesting: You don't need to base your behavior on any study, even if it is scientific.

Let's pretend, for example, that we could find a scientifically valid study that shows that people spend 25% more when using a credit card than they do when spending cash.  This does not mean that if you use a credit card, you will spend 25% more.  All it means is that the average person spending with a credit card spends more than the average person paying cash.  But there are outliers.  There are plenty of people who are being frugal while using a credit card, and there are others who spend too much cash.  Everyone's situation is different.  The idea that *you* will automatically spend less by using cash would not be proven by such a study.

When hearing any type of advice like this, you need to look at your own situation and see if it applies to your own life.  And that is what people are doing with the anecdotal comments.  Some say, "Yep, I spend too much if I use a card." Others say, "Actually, I find that when I have cash in my wallet, I spend it on junk."  And both are correct.  It doesn't matter what the study says the average person does, because you are not average.

Now, let's say that you are a financial counselor who helps people work through disastrous financial messes.  Your client has $20,000 in credit card debt and is having trouble paying all his bills.  He doesn't have a budget and never uses cash.  Probably the best advice for this guy is to stop using his card and start paying cash.  It doesn't take a scientific study to see that this guy needs to change his behavior.

For what it is worth, I keep a strict budget, keeping track of my spending on the computer.  The vast majority of my spending is electronic.  I find tracking my cash spending difficult, and sometimes I find that when I have cash in my wallet, it seems to disappear without a trace.  :)

Comment: Great points, Ben.  As you may have guessed, my main purpose is to see if the theory is suitable when helping people _in general_ with financial questions, but you are certainly correct that behavior is individual.

Comment: @DStanley The interesting thing about helping people in general with their finances is that only the people that are in trouble need help.  That skews the appropriate advice for them.  Take, for example, Dave Ramsey.  His callers are mainly people deeply in debt and trying to get out.  Those are the people who need to hear, "Cut up your card and start paying cash."  The ones who are responsible card users don't get in debt and don't need to call Dave Ramsey.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that there is any good way a study can average this and bring a useful result:

The core problem is that there are people that will spend more money than they should, if they become technically able to, and the credit card is just one of the tools they abuse for that (similar to re-financing with cash-outs, zero percent loans, etc.).

On the other side, there are people who control and understand their spending, and again, the mechanism of payment is irrelevant for them.

Studies measure some mix between the groups, and come up with irrelevant correlations that have no causality.

If you think any tool or mechanics got you in financial trouble, think again: your spending habits and lack of understanding or care get you in financial trouble - nothing else. In a world where it is considered cool to 'don't understand math', it is no surprise that so many people can't control their finances.

Comment: "irrelevant correlations that have no causality" - beautiful phrase.

Answer (score 6):

I thought I'd see if the credit card companies had anything to say about this while trying to get merchants to sign up. I went to [visa.com](https://usa.visa.com/), clicked "Run Your Business" in the top nav, then "[Accept Visa Payments](https://usa.visa.com/run-your-business/accept-visa-payments.html)". This page has a "More benefits of accepting Visa" link with an overlay (which I can't easily link directly to), which includes these lines:

> #### Larger transactions
>
> While the average cash transaction is $17, credit card purchases average $70 while debit card purchases average $36.²
>
> ² Visa Payment Panel Study (2Q11 to 1Q12 time period); Visa MARS Data: March 2015 – May 2015

That obviously doesn't tell the entire story (I suspect people are more likely to pull out cash when they're just buying a stick of gum, and more more likely to pull out a card when they're buying large electronics), but certainly there is some evidence from the credit card companies themselves that people spend more when using cards, which is one of the aspects they use to convince merchants to accept cards.

I think the best evidence that people spend more is that more and more merchants accept cards. Accepting cards comes with some significant costs (though it's important to keep in mind that accepting cash can come with some significant costs as well). I suspect that merchants wouldn't do so unless the increased sales that they get for accepting cards makes up for the fees that they need to pay and the equipment they need to buy to accept them (not to mention the risks of chargebacks and the like).

Comment: In the last 10-15 years (in the USA), "more and more merchants" now includes fast food and even soda/snack vending machines, whereas before you always needed cash to satisfy your cravings.

Answer (score 5):

Unless a study accounts for whether the users are following a budget or not, it is irrelevant to those who are trying to take their personal finances seriously. I can certainly believe that those who have no budget will spend more on a credit card than they will on a debit card or with cash.

Under the right circumstances spending with cards can actually be a tool to track and reduce spending. If you can see on a monthly and yearly basis where all of your money was spent, you have the information to make decisions about the small expenses that add up as well as the obvious large expenses.

Debit cards and credit cards offer the same advantage of giving you an electronic record of all of your transactions, but debit cards do not come with the same fraud protection that credit cards have, so I (and many people like me) prefer to use credit cards for security reasons alone. Cash back and other rewards points bolster the case for credit cards over debit cards.

It is very possible to track all of your spending with cash, but it is also more work. The frustration of accounting for bad transcriptions and rechecking every transaction multiple times is worth discussing too (as a reason that people get discouraged and give up on budgeting).

My point is simply that credit cards and the electronic records that they generate can greatly simplify the process of tracking your spending. I doubt any study out there accounts for the people who are specifically using those benefits and what effect it has on their spending.

Comment: The fraud protection level IMHO depends on where you are. E.g. here in Germany the debit cards work with automatic withdrawals that have a comparably low level of immediate fraud protection, but this is offset by the possibility to reclaim any automatic payment as unjustified. In which case you immediately get back the money and the other side has to prove that their claim was justified. Whereas for my credit card, if I claim an unjustified transaction, *I* have to show the withdrawal was unjustified.

Comment: I think one key sentence here, at least for me, is the key difference between card spending vs cash. "spending with cards can actually be a tool to track and reduce spending".  That's asking my money "where it went".  If I have an envelope of cash labeled "food", I'm telling my money "where to go".  A little too frivolous with restaurants this week?  I guess we're eating out of the pantry the rest of the week!

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 Great, you spent it on food. Great record. Very informative. However, I know how much I spent eating out, which restaurants I'm most likely to spend extra on, what my average grocery trip costs with years of records to analyze on my computer. I also create a budget each month before I start, so not only do I tell it where to go, but I can look back at any time to see where it went. I don't spend money willy-nilly just because I can.

Comment: @NathanL I understand what you mean, and I can even agree.  I am very confident you live on a strict, controlled, budget. But I have several friend who think that just because they track their expenses in Mint, they are "on a budget", but after talking to them, I realize they clearly are just tracking, not planning.  This is where I think cash helps some people who want to get more organized.  It's just "envelope empty", there's no going online to see how close you are to going over for a category.  Spending with cards can be a tool, but frequently aren't.

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 the opening words of my answer acknowledge all of those people who are spending without a plan. I agree that tracking is insufficient. I dislike the envelope system because I feel like it only emphasizes the planning part. Both the plan and the account of the execution are needed for real improvement. Neither is sufficient. And of the two, I feel like accounting for your expenses to the penny is much harder than allocating money to be spent on a monthly basis. I do love how much simpler it is to account for the spending with cards. I can spend less than an hour each month.

Comment: When I used to account with cash, I often spent 3-4 hours before I could balance my accounts down to the penny. It was terribly frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

One study found that, **while people using gift certificates bought no more items than those who used cash, they tended to spend more per item**.

In "Study 3" the paper "[Monopoly money: The effect of payment coupling and form on spending behavior](http://204.14.132.173/pubs/journals/releases/xap143213.pdf)", sets up a case where shoppers are given $50 in cash and $50 in gift certificates (the leftover of which can be exchanged for cash). They were asked to choose different brands and types of items to buy.

They study found that

> There was no difference in the number of items purchased as a
>   function of payment form for scrip

However

> means across all product categories show that
>   participants spent more per item when they were given [the gift certificate]

Comment: See my second bullet point.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer I read it a couple times but I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me.

Comment: That such studies only prove exactly what you stated, "$50 in cash and $50 in gift certificates" are spent using different behavior and results. This does not multiply up to proving anything about a $40,000/yr budget.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're taking issue with the gift certificates vs credit cards or the amounts involved. Can you clarify your clarification?

Comment: I am saying that contrived studies using these relatively tiny sums proves nothing.

Comment: If I am understanding your position correctly then, you would say that  (1) the study in question does not indicate that during a single shopping trip a person is more or less likely to spend differently based on whether they were paying with cash, credit, or gift certificate and (2) even if it did, this difference in spending is not significant enough to make a dent in a yearly budget after factoring in fixed costs (like insurance). Is that correct?